# "going to do" vs. "going to be doing"

Tags: meaning

**Note**: this post is different to ["going to be doing" vs "going to do"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15668/108867), which just cites part from somewhere else, without any further analysis and thinking. Furthermore, none of the answers to that post answers my question - the situations where "will (going to) be doing" is more appropriate.

---

> I will be participating in IELTS test next Tuesday afternoon.

In an online class, the teacher says the following at the beginning of the lesson.

> I will be using NotePod (pointed out by red rectangle) to write relevant points we talk about today.

[image: Screenshot of online class]

I guess "will be using" is more appropriate than "will use" there, right?

---

A [post](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/modal1c.html) explains

> This "tense" is used for reporting a **scheduled activity** with special focus on its timing— as if one is standing in the future and experiencing the flow of the time. The focus is on the temporary, ongoing, or repetitive nature of the activity.

---

I understand the grammar rules of those verb tenses and the difference between this group

> I am going to drive home tomorrow.

> I am going to be driving home tomorrow.

The former is just convey my activity in the near future while the latter probably makes an implication that "don't disturb me as I am driving in that time"

However, in the following situations, I don't see the difference between 2 verb tenses.

> Welcome back to this class. Today's lesson is for the IELTS
> students who are **going to be taking** the
> IELTS test. it's for everybody to be
> honest with you. this lesson is useful
> for anybody who needs to do some writing.

> who are **going to take** the
> IELTS test ...

[source](https://youtu.be/CK_PE9ILJjQ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["going to be doing" vs "going to do"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15668/going-to-be-doing-vs-going-to-do)

Comment: In this context, I'd say there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You tend to use "will be doing" or "going to be doing" when you are referring to something happening at a specific point in the future.

For example, if someone said "Do you want to go to the park at 3:00?", you might say, "No, I will **be doing** the laundry", meaning that you will be unavailable at 3:00 because at that specific point in time, you intend to be doing something else.

However, you would use "will do" or "going to do" when the time is unknown or unspecified. For example, "Do you have any plans for this evening?", you might respond with, "I am going **to do** the laundry." You have not specified exactly when.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the use of "will (going to) be doing" is an example of untidy writing.

To explain this I will use the actions in conjunction with "...the laundry."

Future tense:

A1 **I** am *going to be doing* the laundry. MESSY!

Solution; make it clear **who** and *when* the laundry will be done.

A2 **I** *will do* the laundry.

Present tense:

B1 **I** am *doing* the laundry.

Past tense:

C1 **I** *did* the laundry

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Traveler. We prefer answers that stick to the subject of the question. This question is about spoken English in a YouTube video, so your comments about written English- even if they are correct- are not really relevant to the question,

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score -2):

I'm just trying to think about the intention behind his usage, so I have no sources to prove. May he be trying to convey the feelings and emotions of a person who (in the future and for sure) is going to be at the desk, answering the IELTS exam questions. He is drawing a picture in the future so he uses a continuous tense like "will be taking" but at the same time he is also pointing at its certainty by saying "**going to be** taking"

I am not a native speaker of English as you can see how I construct my sentences and how I use vocabulary but I have been an English teacher for 5 years and I read a lot about grammar rules.

I have just googled it and gotten various answers in a bunch of forums by native speakers. And some of the natives don't even differentiate what is continuous or not in the future and use it interchangeably.

Finally, I checked Advanced Grammar in English written by Martin Hewings and there isn't a section where "be going to be doing" is explained.

Comment: This is a non-answer. If you didn't find a definitive answer, don't post an answer.